# How to get the Current Cursor Coordinates with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

**EDIT:** Solved

My problem is that I need to find a way to constantly read x,y coordinates of the cursor in my browser `onmousedown` and then to quit reading the x,y coordinates `onmouseup` here is what I have so far:

```
var mouseDown = 0;
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;

document.body.onmousedown = function() { 
  mouseDown = 1;
}
document.body.onmouseup = function() {
  mouseDown = 0;
}
function resize(width, height){
    document.getElementById('component1').width=width;
    document.getElementBYId('component1').height=height;
}
function setSize(){
    while(mouseDown == 1)
    {
        xPos = event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
        yPos = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? 
document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
        resize(xPos, yPos);
    }
    
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://javascript.internet.com/page-details/mouse-coordinates.html for a working example

Comment: I can't get this to work when mousedown event occurs. How would you do it?

Comment: @Matt is this the same page http://www.javascriptsource.com/page-details/mouse-coordinates.html as your link is now dead?

Comment: @DaveAnderson yeah that's got pretty much the same thing going on